# Add class to all parent elements inside the_content

Tags: filters, hooks, the-content, regex, post-content

Is there a way to add a class to all parent elements inside the_content?

My problem is I'm using this kind of css selector:

```
.post_content>* {margin-bottom:10px;}
```

This is to due with mostly paragraphs, but also any other element that might be added to the post which won't be wrapped in a paragraph.

I thought the best way to avoid this (as its an expensive selector) would be to add a class to those elements.

I would like a php solution, a filter in the_content that would let me add (not replace) the class of elements just below .post_content (or parent elements in $content).

Thank you

Comment: Would you mind telling us _why_ you're trying to do that? Maybe there's a fix for the _root_ of the problem.

Comment: I just try to avoid the use of * selector. I want each paragraph or other element (ul,div...) (which are parent of the_content "result") to have certain css properties, for example margin-bottom. I just want to know if there is a way of avoid the use of the star selector.Thanks

Comment: But why do you need to space _anything_ that far? That was my question.